# how do i run this code on other computers (relative path c# wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf, path

How do I make this run on other computers i have tried all the things that comes up with relative path c# wpf and checked the other posts here on stackoverflow about it but haven't got any luck it still can't find the file

Sorry for bad English

```
using System.Diagnostics

private void btnDiscord_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Users\\morten\\AppData\\Local\\Discord\\app- 
            0.0.306\\Discord.exe");
            p.Start();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Discord Not Found");
        }
}
```

Comment: You may google about how does windows "PATH" work.

Answer (score 1):

Appdata\Local is referenced in Windows systems as %localappdata%

Appdata\Roaming is referenced as %appdata%

Then you have to do

```
using System.Diagnostics
private void btnDiscord_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       try
       {
           Process p = new Process();
           var path= Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%localappdata%\\Discord\\app- 
           0.0.306\\Discord.exe");
           p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(path); //work with folders in this way is baaad
           p.Start();
       }
       catch
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Discord Not Found");
       }
   }
```

I will find discord app this way:

- I get Discord localappdata folder (%localappdata%\Discord).
- I start find in subfolders for the "Discord.exe" file and break the loops when found.

Notice that this doesn't assert you nothing. You could using an old version, or not find nothing if they choose to change the name of the exe file.

If discord subfolders use a pattern (they do, for now... You never know when you're app will break) you can do:

- Subfolder name which contains "app" and is alphabetically greater.

  ```
  public string FindDiscordFile() {
     var subfolders = Directory.GetDirectories(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%localappdata%\\Discord"));
     var subfolder = subfolders.Where(folder=> folder.StartsWith("app")).Max(folder=> folder);
     return subfolder+"\\Discord.exe";
  }
  ```

Comment: You can't directly use environment variables in methods like `GetDirectories`. You need to combine it with `Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables`.

Comment: @John true, my fault, fast writing, not thinking, Thanks

Comment: No worries! I do it all the time :)